# Finding $\alpha$ and $\beta$ so that function becomes continuous

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions, continuity

\begin{align*}
f: (0,2] &\to \mathbb{C},\\
x &\mapsto x^2 \sin(\pi/x) + ix^2, \quad x \in (0, 1]\\
x &\mapsto \alpha e^\frac{1}{1-x}+i\beta e^x. \quad x \in (1, 2]
\end{align*}

I need to show that $f$ is continuous on $(0, 1)$ and $(1, 2]$ which I managed to do using sequences. Then I need to determine whether $\alpha$ and $\beta$ can be chosen to make $f$ continuous on $(0, 2]$. So I need to check if it's possible to pick $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in order to make
$$\lim_{x\to 1^-} f(x)=f(x) = \lim_{x\to 1^+}f(x),$$
which means f is continuous at $1$.

The problem is: $f(x) = \alpha e^\frac{1}{1-x}+i\beta e^x$  would result in divison by zero when $\lim_{x\to 1} f(x)$.

I thought about picking $\alpha=\frac{-1}{e^\frac{1}{1-x}}+\frac{1}{e^\frac{1}{1-x}}$ and $\beta=\frac{1}{e}$, because then
$$f(x) = \alpha e^\frac{1}{1-x}+i\beta e^x = \left(\frac{-1}{e^\frac{1}{1-x}}+\frac{1}{e^\frac{1}{1-x}}\right) e^\frac{1}{1-x}+\frac{i}{e} e^x = (-1+1)+\frac{i}{e}e^x$$ and therefore $f(1)= i$.

The last question is if $f$ can be made continuous on all of $\mathbb{R}$ and if yes, how?

I'm rather sure that my idea won't work, so I would appreciate your help!

Comment: You cannot pick an $\alpha$ depending on $x$, it should be a constant. Which constant you must take in order to get rid of the term $e^{\frac{1}{1-x}}$?

Comment: Well, 0. Is my $\beta$ correct?

Comment: Yes it is. And when you have these values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ the second part is fairly easy.